# LISP- simple functions , syntax error?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm currently trying to learn lisp and am using emacs on linux. To the best of my ability, I have written two functions.

*Both functions first remove the first element of the list.*

- `series` adds all the elements in the given list.
- `parallel`
          1) takes the inverse of each number in the list, then 
          2) adds all the elements in the list, then 
          3) takes the inverse of the sum of the elements.

---

Code:

```
(defun series (lst)
    (apply #'+' (cdr lst)) )

(defun parallel (lst)
    (/ 1 (apply #'+' (apply #'/' (cdr 'lst ) ) ) ))
```

---

I can evaluate the function, but when I try to use the function, as below:

```
(series (list 3 3 4 5))
```

I get the error : **value CDR is not of the expected type NUMBER.**
   I see this, and I think, why is emacs treating cdr as a number rather than a function?
I'm new to lisp and emacs, so I don't know to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE

I've the problems in this code and I think it works...

```
(defun series (lst)
 (apply #'+ (cdr lst) ))

(defun parallel(lst)
(/ 1 (apply #'+ (mapcar #'/ (make-list (- (length lst) 1) :initial-element 1) (cdr lst)  ) )))
```

Hopefully, what I was trying to do is understood now.

Comment: The `'` notation in Lisp is very different from quoted character strings. There is no closing quote. `'<anything>` is a shorthand which stands for the list structure `(quote <anything>)`. This is useful because when `(quote <anything>)` is evaluated, the value is always object `<anything>` itself, whatever it is. The value of `(quote (+ 2 2))` is the list `(+ 2 2)` rather than `4`.  Lisp has a double quote for string literals, like `"abc"`, and character constants have a '#\' (hash backslash) syntax which has some variety in it such as '#\space' denoting space and '#\A' denoting upper case A.

Comment: @Kaz this should definitely go into your answer, not stay hidden in comments. :)

Comment: in Common LISP `mapcar` stops when shorter list ends. This means, *circular list* can be used to supply the default argument: `(nth 5 (setq b '(1.0) b (rplacd b b))) ==> 1.0`. Don't know about emacs-Lisp though. btw do you get same answer when using `1` and `1.0`?

Comment: Hmmm....... I'm not familiar with circular lists, but the concept seems more intuitive. In this case, both lists next to `mapcar` are guaranteed to be the same length.                                           I also saw                                                          `'#1='(1 2 3 . #1#)`                                                       as an example of a circular list. Does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra apostrophes that are confusing the LISP parser.  The syntax to refer to the `+` function is just `#'+`; there's no "close quote".

Comment: Also, no quote on `lst` in `(cdr 'lst)`.

Comment: Ahhh... I see now, I wrote it wrong. Removing the extra quotes (as in  Kaz's comment  & Reed's answer) fixed the problems in this code.

Comment: Yes, and note there can be whitespace between `'` and whatever follows, so that `'A' B` actually means the same thing as `'A 'B`.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

```
(defun parallel (lst)
    (/ 1 (apply #'+' (apply #'/' (cdr 'lst ) ) ) ))
```

Why *are* you trying to discard the first element. That is curious.

Note that the logic of this function won't work even if the quoting issues are solved.

`(apply #'/ (cdr lst))` will pass the remainder of `lst` to the `/` function. This function will produce a number.

And so you then effectively `(apply #'+ number)`, problem being that `apply` wants a list.

The parallel semantics you are hinting at will not happen.

Perhaps you want this:

```
 ;; divide the sum of the remaining elements, by the fraction of those elements
 (/ (apply #'+ (cdr lst)) (apply #'/ (cdr lst)))
```

Note that in Emacs Lisp, division of integers by integers yields an integer, and not a rational like in Common Lisp.

Comment: the OP wants to "take[...] the inverse of each number in the list". That's `(mapcar #'/ (cdr lst))`. The names `series` and `parallel` probably refer to calculations of ohmic resistance in electrical circuits. :)

Comment: @WillNess that's exactly what I meant to do :)

Comment: @Kaz I've edited my answer to include the updated code, so what I was trying to accomplish can be understood.

Comment: @WillNess I got a mortarboard badge over in Electronics yesterday and it didn't occur to me.  Say, I don't have an installation of Emacs handy right now, but looking at the GNU Emacs manual online, it appears that  one-argument form of the `/` function is not documented! In Common Lisp `(/ x)` does means `(/ 1 x)`, which is analogous to unary minus `(- x)` -> `(- 0 x)`. Is this something that Just Works? If not, you have to do `(mapcar (lambda (num) (/ 1 num)) list)`.

Comment: turns out my old emacs installation is gone too. wasn't a big fan of getting a pain in my left wrist every time I tried using it, after a day or two. ;)